# Changing Navigation Bar Color in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am building a Swift app and I am trying to change the color of the navigation bar.
I'm trying to do it directly from Xcode without code on the main.storyboard.

I've tried changing several settings in the Xcode Attribute Inspector but nothing has worked. I've also searched StackOverFlow but all the answers I find are are changing it programatically.

Does anyone know how to change the color of it directly from the Attribute Inspector?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you searching? If I open a storyboard with a navigation controller and click on the navigation bar, there is a lot of attributes to change its appearance.

Comment: @sulthan Yes, I've changed different Attributes like tint color, background color, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to click on the navbar and in attribute inspector, there is an option for Background, you can provide any color which you want to give. In my case, I selected a custom sky blue color.
[image: Check Screenshot here]

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

or you do this by Storyboard Like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard, change the background color. It will work.

[image]

Comment: It seems Xcode 13.x, 14.x completely ignoring all navigation bar attributes via storyboard, except the prefer large title one. I guess Apple wants to force storyboard users to switch to SwiftUI...

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
   if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
                appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
                appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 21/255, green: 46/255, blue: 82/255, alpha: 1)
                appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, .font: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 32)!]
                navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
                navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance
                navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = appearance.copy()
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to not to it programmatically? Like straight from the attribute inspector?